# Using the same docker images for all the jobs in a workflow of Github actions

Tags: docker, github, caching, github-actions

I want to use the same container for all the jobs in the workflow. However for every job, it fetches the image. Is there any way to override this and get the image before hand and spin off containers from this image.

```
jobs:
  name: job1
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  container: alpine/hello-world
  steps:
    ......
    ......

  name: job2
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  container: alpine/hello-world
  strategy: 
   matrix: ['abc','def']
  steps:
    ......
    ......
```

So in the above, as you can see everytime I use the container, it's going to pull the image. Is there a way to limit this and reuse the image from the job1 and use it in job2. Also in job2, when I use the matrix strategy, it again pulls the image.